# Eclipse 4 RCP Product Export JRE Not Found Error

Tags: java, eclipse, export, rcp

I have an eclipse RCP application which can be exported using the "product export wizard" when I **dont** select the option to "Bundle JRE for this environment for this product".

When I do select the "Bundle JRE for this environment for this product", I get the following error

```
D:\Data\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86.xml:92: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Data\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86.xml:459: 

D:\Data\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\assemblyLocation\tmp\eclipse\jre\bin does not exist.
```

I am using Eclipse SDK 4.3.1 and tried changing the workspace but I am getting the same problem.

Will appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Just a guess, but in `Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments` is the Execution Environment assigned to a particular JRE?

Comment: Execution environments are configured as per your suggestion. I have JRE6 and JDK 1.7 installed on my windows xp machine. The **Execution Environments** settings can pick up both and I tried assigning defaults with both options but still I have this issue